# Calling data entered into a string

Tags: java

I am working on a program for school and I am running into an error that I am having a really hard time solving. I have checked my text book, this site and other sites and I am missing something.

It is probably very obvious, will someone please take a look at the code below?

I am receiving the following error from jGrasp:

> Error: cannot find symbol
>   result = console.nextString()

/*Design and implement the class Day that implements the day of the week in a program.
 The class Day should store the day, such as Sun for Sunday. The program should be able to perform 
 the following operations on an object of type Day" provide, today, tomorrow, yesterday and a future date. In
 this case it will provide the day in two weeks. Also has a section to test program*/

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Days2 {

    final static int sun = 0;
    final static int mon = 1;
    final static int tues = 2;
    final static int wed = 3;
    final static int thurs = 4;
    final static int fri = 5;
    final static int sat = 6;

    public int today;

    public Days2(int today) {
        this.today = today;
    }

    public void setDay(int today) {
        this.today = today;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return today;
    }

    public int tomorrow() {
        if (today == sat) {
            return sun;
        } else {
            today = (today + 1) % 7;
        }
        return today;
    }

    public int yesterday() {
        if (today == 0) {
            return sat;
        } else {
            today = (today - 1) % 7;
        }
        return today;
    }

    public int twoWeeks(int todays) {
        return ((today + todays) - 1) % 7;
    }

    public String toString() {
        switch (this.today) {
            case sun:
                return "Sunday";
            case mon:
                return "Monday";
            case tues:
                return "Tuesday";
            case wed:
                return "Wednesday";
            case thurs:
                return "Thursday";
            case fri:
                return "Friday";
            case sat:
                return "Saturday";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result;
        System.out.println("Please enter what day it is. (Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri or Sat");
        result = console.nextString();

        //In order to test this program, enter a variable declared in the
        //beginning of the code instead of result into the object outDay listed
        //below.
        Days2 outDay = new Days2(result);
        System.out.print("Today is" + " " + outDay);
        System.out.println();
        outDay.setDay(outDay.yesterday());
        System.out.print("Yesterday was" + " " + outDay);
        System.out.println();
        outDay.setDay(outDay.tomorrow());
        outDay.setDay(outDay.tomorrow());
        System.out.print("Tomorrow is" + " " + outDay);
        System.out.println();
        outDay.setDay(outDay.twoWeeks(14));
        System.out.print("In two weeks it will be" + " " + outDay + " " + "again.");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `console.next()` or `console.nextLine()` (depending upon what you want, I leave rest to you) ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Error: cannot find symbol result = console.nextString() ^

Since Scanner does n't have a method called `nextString()`.

[Scanner doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_detail)

Use [`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)) to read string.

```
result = console.next();
```

---

But according to you program you need to read `int` not `String`.

So change type of `result` to `int` from `String`.

```
int result;
```

To read `int`, `Scanner` have `nextInt()`.

```
result = console.nextInt();
```

---

Change you message to

```
System.out.println("Please enter what day it is. "+
                  "(Sun-0, Mon-1, Tues-2, Wed-3, Thurs-4, Fri-5 or Sat-6");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the correct syntax for accepting a string is console.next() or console.nextLine()

Another problem with your program is that the constructor Days2 is accepting an int value as argument but you are calling it with a string as argument.

you could change the variable result to an int value and change the command for accepting an integer from the console to console.nextInt()

Comment: Thank you! This was also very helpful!